# svelte: click event triggered on wrong button

Tags: javascript, svelte, svelte-3

I have a svelte app where

1. licking a button "Show" sets a show variable to true which shows a input text box and a save button.
2. Clicking the "Save" button calls a function which sets the show variable to false

Testing shows that clicking Show also triggers the on:click of Save.
Google tells me to add stopPropagation to fix this issue, but it does not fix this issue.
Any hints on what is my mistake?

A repl with my code is available at
https://svelte.dev/repl/592a544ac59a45b385ab153dec7a42f1?version=3.55.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forked the repl and made some changes to it
https://svelte.dev/repl/b897aa42e87d4adc8c04b381b5a66692?version=3.55.1

Here is the new code:

```
<script>
    var name = ''
    let names=[];
    let show=false;
    function addName(){
        console.log("Clicked");
        show=false;
        if (name.length > 0){
            names.push(name);
            console.log(names)
        }
    }
</script>
<button on:click={()=>(show=true)} > Show
</button>
{#if show}
<input bind:value={name} type="text">
<button on:click={()=> {addName()}}>Save</button>
{/if}
<h1>Hello {name}!</h1>
```

You shouldn't have a propogation issue because the event listeners are not nested elements https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/javascript-tutorial/javascript-event-propagation.php

Your Save button on:click was setup like

```
<button on:click={addName()}>Save</button>
```

This definition is not correct because on:click={addName()} calls the addName function immediately. If you use this syntax you likely need to write it like this

```
on:click={addName}
```

Otherwise you can write it like your other on:click with an anonymous function (which is what I did).

```
on:click={()=> {addName()}}
```

Comment: `names` isn't used but if it was, there was an assignment missing after the `names.push(name)` https://svelte.dev/docs#component-format-script-2-assignments-are-reactive It's good to mention the options to write something, but I would always go with the most simple and best to read version to do the fellow devs a favour :)